# Vaadin: Grid Cell Colour, Slow To React

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin-grid

I have Vaadin Spring Boot Application that has a grid that uses a class name generator to style a columns cells. When setItems() is called on this grid the values in the cells are updated almost immediately but the cell colour doesn't change for some time after.

My class uses a Poll to call an update method every 10 seconds which calls setItems() on the grid. See below for a basic example of the set up I am using. In the example below when the update method is called, the overall score value will be updated in an acceptable amount of time, but the colour of the cell is taking too long.

Any advice to speed this up would be great, I'm not that keen on the poll so if anyone thinks that may be the problem I would love to hear your thoughts.

```
@Route("simple-layout")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/grid-styles.css")
public class SimpleLayout extends VerticalLayout { 
    
    private Grid<Student> grid;
    private StudentService service;
    
    public SimpleLayout(StudentService service) {

        ... ommitted other code fragments

        grid.addColumn(Student::getOverallScore).setClassNameGenerator(this::getCellStyle());
        add(grid);

        UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
        ui.setPollInterval(10000);
        PollListenerRegistration pollListenerRegistration = ui.addPollListener(pollEvent -> updateGrid());
    }

    private String getCellStyle(Student student) {
       
        if(student.getOverallScore() > 50) {
            return "green-cell-colour";
        } else {
            return "red-cell-colour";
        }
    }

    private void updateGrid() {
      
        grid.setItems(service.findAll());
    }
}






@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private int overallScore;
    
    public Student() {}
    
    ...getters and setters omitted
} 





@Service
public class StudentService {
    
    private StudentRepo repo;

    public StudentService(StudentRepo repo) {
   
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    
    public List<Student> findAll() {
    
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}






public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    List<Student> findAll();
}
```

Comment: Could you please be specific, _when_ the time is wasted.  E.g. is the time spent inside `getCellStyle` or does ti take 40s to render the grid in the browser? If you can not use a profiler, then at least try to bisect the problem (e.g. don't call `getOverallScore`).  Also what exactly is `StundentService` and what is `Student` (e.g. some Repo and some ORM-mapped class? Is the score materialized? Has the Student lazy-loaded content (n+1-Problem))?

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I have amended my question to hopefully make things abit clearer, I should of mentioned  that my application is not getting hung up anywhere (its not taking along time to load anything) I know this because the values in the rows are updated very quickly. Its almost as if the class name generator runs periodically and my grid is waiting for the next call. (Im sure thats not the case, but thats what its acting like)

Comment: "but the colour of the cell is taking too long" _where_ is it slow? In
the browser? When it polls? I'll second: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)